# numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found :Error while installing scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to install scipy using 
**pip install scipy**, but when i try to do so, I am getting the following lines as error ,

```
       config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 20, in configuration
raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found
```

followed by these in red color,

`Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\
    \users\\nature\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-oazxvd\\scipy\\setup.py';f=geta
    ttr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.clos
    e();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\nature\app
    data\local\temp\pip-ur3_v2-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally
    -managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\nature\appdata\local\t
    emp\pip-build-oazxvd\scipy\`

I don't know what these errors depicts,
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: If you are not familiar with compiling software on windows, please use some alternative binary distribution like [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads). It's the recommend approach by the scipy-devs. (Even if you are familiar: it's not easy)

Answer (score 1):

It has some missing dependencies.
You can either:

1. Install Anaconda and switch your python to it. It has built-in dependencies.
2. Download and install missing package manually. In your case it is "scipy". Go to http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy, select your OS and download. After open cmd in your download folder and launch

   ```
   pip install package-name.whl
   ```